# Scrollbar is overlapping command bar in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, scrollbar, commandbar

Ok, so scrollbar from my Hub (I think) is overlapping my command bar and it is impossible to interact with thee. So how do I disable it (the scollbar)? To get it invisible? I tried adding "ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" to Hub, Grid but it did not helped me at all.

[image]

Here's the XAML of the page:

```
<Page
x:Class="CourseWorkTest.Settings"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:CourseWorkTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <CommandBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="back"  Icon="Back" Label="Back" Click="back_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="save" Icon="Accept" Label="Save" Click="save_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
    <Hub Header="Settings">
        <HubSection Header="General">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Width="500" Height="550" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                        <StackPanel Height="Auto">
                            <Button x:Name="enabledDays" Content="Enabled Days" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" Width="500" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Click="enabledDays_Click">
                                <Button.Flyout>
                                    <MenuFlyout x:Name="enabledDaysMenuFlyout">
                                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem x:Name="mon" Text="Monday" Tag="enabledDay" Click="enabledDays_Click"/>
                                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Tuesday" x:Name="tue" Tag="enabledDay" Click="enabledDays_Click"/>
                                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Wednesday" x:Name="wed" Tag="enabledDay" Click="enabledDays_Click"/>
                                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Thursday" x:Name="thu" Tag="enabledDay" Click="enabledDays_Click"/>
                                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Friday" x:Name="fri" Tag="enabledDay" Click="enabledDays_Click"/>
                                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Saturday" x:Name="sat" Tag="enabledDay" Click="enabledDays_Click"/>
                                        <ToggleMenuFlyoutItem Text="Sunday" x:Name="sun" Tag="enabledDay" Click="enabledDays_Click"/>
                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                </Button.Flyout>
                            </Button>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="enabledDaysText"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Header="Notifications &amp; Automute">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Width="400" Background="WhiteSmoke" Height="550">
                        <ToggleSwitch x:Name="automuteToggleSwitch" Header="Automute" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Automute device during lesson"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Header="Durations">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Width="550" Height="550" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection Header="Data">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Width="300" Height="550" Background="WhiteSmoke">
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Chris's answer is one solution for your problem. You can place a [CommandBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar) inline with your app content, anywhere in your XAML. However more typically, we would assign it to the **App Bar** of a [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page) especially if the `CommandBar` must remain visible to a user when the touch keyboard, or Soft Input Panel (SIP), appears.

As you want to put the `CommandBar` at the `Bottom`, then you can use the [BottomAppBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Page_BottomAppBar) property of a `Page` like

```
<Page x:Class="CourseWorkTest.Settings"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:CourseWorkTest"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="back" Click="back_Click" Icon="Back" Label="Back" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="save" Click="save_Click" Icon="Accept" Label="Save" />
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Hub Header="Settings">
        ...
        </Hub>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

For more info, please see **Placement** in [App bar and command bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/app-bars).

To hide the `ScrollBar`, we need to edit [Hub styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299131.aspx) as [Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Hub) supports scrollview implicitly in its template. In its template, we can find the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property is fixed to `Auto`.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
              Grid.RowSpan="2"
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
              HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
              HorizontalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
              VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
              VerticalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
              VerticalSnapPointsType="OptionalSingle"
              ZoomMode="Disabled">
    <ItemsStackPanel x:Name="Panel" CacheLength="20" Orientation="{TemplateBinding Orientation}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

So we can simply change it to `Hidden` then assign this new style to `Hub`. After this, there should be no scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks you @Chris and Jay both solutions solved half of my problem. Now I can interact with my command bar, but still the scroll bar makes page hideous. How can I make it invisible? Again I tried using "ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" to the Page and Grid but it still visible. But still thanks!

Comment: @stroibot I've updated my answer. Setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` won't work here as it is fixed in  Hub's template. We have to change the style of  `Hub` to hide the scroll bar.

Comment: I have a trouble with this. I tried this but it didn't do a thing: `<Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Hub">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>`

Comment: @stroibot Setting this property in Hub's style also won't work as it is **fixed** in Hub's template. We have to go into Hub's template and set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` in the **ScrollViewer** in  Hub's template.

Comment: Didn't even consider the uwp abbbar space specifics, +1 for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `Grid` the way it's meant to be used in a layout because your current results would be expected in how you have it currently. To fix it, do this;

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Hub></Hub>

  <CommandBar Grid.Row="1"></CommandBar>

</Grid>
```

Cheers!